# How to group a set of parent->children where child can be parent also. Have a solve, but looking for more efficient algorithm

Tags: php, parent-child, relationship, performance

I have a set of data that contains parents and children.  What I'm looking to do is create logical groups that consist of the data that connects to each other.  I have provided the code that I have currently, but I have a sinking feeling that it can be optimized.

```
    $parents= array(
        '1' => array(
            '2' => 'none',
            '3' => 'none',
            '9' => 'none'
        ),  
        '2' => array(
            '4' => 'none',
            '5' => 'none'
        ),  
        '6' => array(
            '7' => 'none',
            '8' => 'none',
            '9' => 'none'
        ),  
        '10' => array(
            '11' => 'none',
            '12' => 'none'
        )
    );

    $groups = array();
    foreach($parents as $parent => $children){
        foreach(array_keys($children) as $child){
            $parentgroup = -1; 
            $childgroup = -1; 
            foreach($groups as $key => $group){
                if(isset($group[$parent])){
                    $parentgroup = $key;
                }   
                if(isset($group[$child])){
                    $childgroup = $key;
                }
            }

            if($parentgroup == -1 && $childgroup == -1){
                $groups[] = array($parent => true, $child => true);
            }
            else {
                if($childgroup == -1){
                    $groups[$parentgroup][$child] = true;
                } else if($parentgroup == -1){
                    $groups[$childgroup][$parent] = true;
                } else if($parentgroup != $childgroup){
                    foreach($groups[$childgroup] as $val => $none){
                        $groups[$parentgroup][$val] = true;
                    }
                    unset($groups[$childgroup]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($groups);

    // Result
    Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [6] => 1
                [7] => 1
                [8] => 1
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 1
                [3] => 1
                [9] => 1
                [4] => 1
                [5] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [10] => 1
                [11] => 1
                [12] => 1
            )

    )
```

I also took a go at it a different way, but I ran into a problem with the later nodes.  This carried a bonus of incrementing when an item was used so that I could determine weight later on:

```
    function BGR($users, $group){
        global $pass1;
        foreach ($users as $id => $none){
            $group[$id]++;
            if(isset($pass1[$id])){
                $children = $pass1[$id];
                unset($pass1[$id]);
                $group = BGR($children, $group);
            }
        }
        return $group;
    }

    $groups = array();
    while($pass1){
        $id = key($pass1);
        $parent = $pass1[$id];
        unset($pass1[$id]);
        $groups[] = BGR($parent, array( $id => 1));
    }
    print_r($groups);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we found a solution for the second block above which seems to reduce the processing time by about 20%.  Turns out that the method was sound, but the data needed to be in a better place.  We could either format the data initially to be something like:

```
    $parents= array(
        '1' => array(
            '2' => 'none',
            '3' => 'none',
            '9' => 'none'
        ),  
        '2' => array(
            '1' => 'none',
            '3' => 'none',
            '9' => 'none',
            '4' => 'none',
            '5' => 'none'
        ),
        '3' => array(
            '1' => 'none',
            '2' => 'none',
            '9' => 'none'
        ),
        '4' => array(
            '2' => 'none',
            '5' => 'none'
        ),
        '5' => array(
            '2' => 'none',
            '4' => 'none'
        ),
        '6' => array(
            '7' => 'none',
            '8' => 'none',
            '9' => 'none'
        ),  
        '7' => array(
            '6' => 'none',
            '8' => 'none',
            '9' => 'none'
        ),  
        '8' => array(
            '6' => 'none',
            '7' => 'none',
            '9' => 'none'
        ),  
        '9' => array(
            '6' => 'none',
            '7' => 'none',
            '8' => 'none'
        ),  
        '10' => array(
            '11' => 'none',
            '12' => 'none'
        ),  
        '11' => array(
            '10' => 'none',
            '12' => 'none'
        ),  
        '12' => array(
            '10' => 'none',
            '11' => 'none'
        )
    );
```

Or we could take a pass at the data in it's current state, and get it to a state where we can go through it recursively, and touch all of the points:

```
    $pass2 = array();
    foreach ($pass1 as $parent => $children){
        foreach($children as $child => $none){
            $pass2[$parent][$child] = true;
            $pass2[$child][$parent] = true;
        }   
    }
```